# Python 3.3 in Wamp (Apache 2.4.2 – Mysql 5.5.24 – PHP 5.4.3)

Tags: python, wamp

I am looking at getting python up and running with my WAMP setup.
I need it to test some py apps I am learning to build.
I see that Mod_wsgi project was terminated and that was pretty much the only way I found on how to run python on WAMP.

Can anyone advise how to get it up and running?
Thank you so much

Comment: mod_wsgi was terminated? Where did you get that from? [As far as I can see, the project is still active](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mod_wsgi` is an active, working project, and you have essentially answered your own question, you should use it.

You may have been thinking of `mod_python`, a different, discontinuted project that has been superseeded by `mod_wsgi`.

I would suggest you follow [this guide](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide).

Comment: Thank you for the reply Lattyware, on the [mod_wsgi download page](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/downloads/list) I only find at best (Win32/Apache 2.2/Python 3.1). So my question is will it run on my configuration (Apache 2.4.2 – Mysql 5.5.24 – PHP 5.4.3) using python 3.3?

Comment: @superuseroi You should try compiling from the source on the latest version.

Comment: @superuseroi Compiling from source isn't a great skill - there will be a readme that walks you through the process. It'll probably be a bit harder under windows, but just grab MinGW or something and it should be fine.

Comment: @superuseroi https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationOnWindows#Compiling_From_Source_Code

Comment: thank you so much for your patience and guidance! If possible I have few doubts still:
- the wiki says "To compile from source code you will need Microsoft C/C++ compiler for Windows" you pointed to MinGW, do I need them both or are they the same kind tools and only one of them should be used?
- the wiki continues with " This must be the same version of the compiler as used to build the version of Python being used" I don't know how python was compiled, will this be an issue?